# Preview changes not working

Tags: wordpress

My problem here is when I edit a post and click 'Preview changes', the changes do not take place in the preview. I deactivated all the plugins I have and activated those one at a time and at the same time, I also tried editing the post, preview changes and the changes took place. When I activated the plugin 'Exec-PHP', my problem starts there. By clicking 'Preview changes', the changes do not take effect in my post. This is actually the first time it happened because in the other sites I made, 'Exec-PHP' is activated and the 'Preview changes' works.

Comment: try clearing your browser cache (Ctrl + Shift + Delete)

Answer (score 1):

This is plugin not work in current version of wordpress 3.8 and this plugin is use in wordpress 3.1.1 version so please use other plugin .

Comment: I'm using an old version of Wordpress. My problem is not about the plugin, it works fine. My problem is that my 'Preview changes' button does not apply the changes to the post because of this plugin.

Comment: which version you use ?

Comment: this  plugin is not supported for Wordpress 3.1.4 version

Comment: It works. Again, the problem is the 'Preview changes' button in the post. It does not apply the changes because Exec-PHP is activated.

Comment: So please Deactivated   Exec-PHP plugin because  Exec-PHP plugin is not supported in wordpress 3.1.4 version

Comment: It is actually supported and I need that plugin in the site.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/
download install 
this new version of Exec-PHP plugin
do work same both plugin

Comment: put a this code
[wp-pdf-view
    swf="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/upload/[view_repo].swf"
    width="700"
    height="900"

/]